# ES modules: deprecate export

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, deprecation-warning

As a library mantainer, I want to **deprecate an old export** in favour of a new one.

In order to keep backward compatibility I'd like to temporary **keep both exports** and **warn those users** who are still **using the old one**.

**Before**

```
function foo(){}
export {foo as oldExport}
```

**After**

```
function foo(){}
export {foo as newExport}
export {foo as oldExport} // When user import it I'd like to fire a `console.warn`
```

The only solutions I came up with consist of using **[external](https://github.com/TooTallNate/util-deprecate) [libraries](https://github.com/dougwilson/nodejs-depd)** or **wrapping the exported function in another deprecated function**. Which I don't consider optimal for a small library like the one I'm working on.

Is there any other approach I have overlooked?

Comment: How would you do a deprecation warning when not keeping the function in a new export? It seems like wrapping the function is the way to go anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official way to do that in JavaScript (as far as I know).

One way that at least works in IntelliJ IDEA and probably most other IDEs is the one below. It will mark any import and any usage of `oldExport` as deprecated (by default formatted with a strike-through).

```
function foo() {}
export {foo as newExport}

/**
 * @deprecated
 */
const oldExport = foo;
export {oldExport}
```

See http://usejsdoc.org/tags-deprecated.html

If a log message is absolutely necessary (I would not do that), then you have to do it by yourself.

Comment: This is really useful thank you. I had tried marking the export as deprecated, but it only worked once using a variable.

Answer (score 0):

`export const data=[{},{}];`-------> **produces error**

***the way you can export things from js files......***

```
module.exports={data};
```

**and in importing file you can write...(in which you want to import this data)**

```
const {data}=require('./data');
```